Is my gear's sell value the same at every shop in Hogwarts Legacy?
I have lots of gear that I'd like to sell, but where is the best place to sell them?
Are the prices (sell value) the same at every shop?

Like let's say as an example if one shop offers me 80 gold for a robe, would the price also be 80 gold at all other shops? Or do the prices vary depending on the shop?

You should get the same price from every shop.
According to IGN, the price of each tier is fixed, meaning that you always get the same amount.

Here is how much gear would sell for depending on their rarity:

Green Gear: 60 Galleons
Blue Gear: 90 Galleons
Purple Gear: 150 Galleons
Gold Gear: 200 Galleons


